# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES KeyGenerator not available while deploy on jboss

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

I have a problem and I need your help. I get this error while deploying my project on jboss:

```
Unexpected exception initializing encryption.  No encryption will be performed.: javax.faces.FacesException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES KeyGenerator not available
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ByteArrayGuard.setupKeyAndMac(ByteArrayGuard.java:232)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ByteArrayGuard.<init>(ByteArrayGuard.java:89)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.init(ClientSideStateHelper.java:496)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.<init>
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: AES KeyGenerator not available
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.<init>(KeyGenerator.java:169)
    at javax.crypto.KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyGenerator.java:223)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ByteArrayGuard.setupKeyAndMac(ByteArrayGuard.java:226)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: What version/flavor of Java is it running on?

Comment: Which code throws the error?

Comment: I'm using jdk 1.8.0_112. I just start Jboss to deploy my project on Jboss IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Every implementation of Java is required to support a few standard algorithms like AES or DES. This is stated in the [documentation of `KeyGenerator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html). So you probably have a problem with your Java environment setup.

In oracle's java implementation the algorithm classes should be located in `sunjce_provider.jar` (at least with version 1.7 and 1.8), which is usually located under `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext`.

A common failure is, that this directory is not in your classpath, which might happen, when you explicitly define an extension-dir via

```
java -Djava.ext.dirs=/my/other/dir <more arguments...>
```

If you specify an extension-dir this way, you should also include `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext` (and make sure `JAVA_HOME` is set correctly):

```
java -Djava.ext.dirs=/my/other/dir:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext  <more arguments...>
```

In JBoss/Wildfy this is usually done in the configuration file `bin/standalone.conf` (or `bin/run.conf` in older versions).
Details about java extensions and their configuration can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/spec.html#installed).

Comment: I've personally never seen that lib/ext was not on the classpath, but I have seen that AES was not *activated* by default